# MVC Radiobutton Validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I am trying to do some validation for a radio button set where the user must select one option.
I am using the jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js.
for validating the checkboxes and textbox, I am using

```
     [MustBeTrue(ErrorMessage = "You must 18")]` 
     public bool IsEighteenYear { get; set; }    
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Your first name is required.")]
     public string FirstName {get; set;}
```

respectively in the model.
Is there a similar way to do it for the radio buttons?
Say like I have

```
    public int Prefix { get; set;}
```

in the model which are radio buttons?

My views looks like

```
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Is18)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Prefix)
```

Comment: Are you asking how to do validations on `int` versus `boolean` types?

Comment: I was asking how to validate those radio  buttons so that user must select one?
Like Im doing, Mustbetrue for the checkbox, required for the textbox, so is there something like that for radiobuttons?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
[Required()]
public string Prefix { get; set;}

@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Prefix, "Mr.") Mr.
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Prefix, "Ms.") Ms.
```

The trick is to use a string type so you can enforce the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, a better approach would be to use nullables. For example:

`public int? Prefix { get; set;}`

This way you can have [Requried] for value types (enums as well) and you won't have to handle parsing of the string values.